Reply Depend on current and previous Status
I have this code  tend to achieve this
If the user has previously asked about Nrat and then says "Thank you": The reply should respond with a specific Nrat-related response.
If the user just says "Thank you" without previously asking about Nrat: The reply should respond with a general "Thank you" response.
but reply always triggers to General thanks even user ask previous about Nrat
function handleDialogyManagement( ) {
        global $lastIntent,$currentIntent,$checkcurrentStatus;
        $checkcurrentStatus=false;
        if($checkcurrentStatus){
            if($lastIntent === 'Nrat_Identity' || $lastIntent === 'Nrat_Office_Location'){
                $checkcurrentStatus=true;
                }else{
                    $checkcurrentStatus=false;
            }
         
        }
        
    
         if (($lastIntent === 'Nrat_Identity' || $lastIntent === 'Nrat_Office_Location') && $currentIntent === 'Thank_You') {
           
         
            // Generate a random index to select one of the predefined responses
            $randomIndex = rand(0, 2); // Adjust the range based on the number of responses
    
            // Predefined responses based on your requirements
            $responses = [
                "I'm happy to help about Nrat",
                
                "I'm grateful that my answer about Nrat"
        
               
            ];
    
            
            // Assign the selected response to the answer field in the response array
            $response['answer'] = $responses[$randomIndex];

            return $response;
        }

     
        if ( $currentIntent === 'Thank_You' && $checkcurrentStatus===false) {
            // Generate a random index to select one of the predefined responses
            $randomIndex = rand(0, 2); // Adjust the range based on the number of responses
    
          
            $responses = [
              "your welcome.",
"My pleasure",


            ];
    
            
            $response['answer'] = $responses[$randomIndex];

            return $response;
        }

    
            
    
    }
    
    

1-If the user has previously asked about Nrat and then says "Thank you": The reply should respond with a specific Nrat-related response.
2-If the user just says "Thank you" without previously asking about Nrat: The reply should respond with a general "Thank you" response.

Because $lastIntent is always equal to Murat_Identity

i put $lastIntent=Nrat by example sorry i updated the code last intent was fetched from database when user ask about murat last intent being murat but when user type thanks only last intent is murant and current intent is thanks

Now $lastIntent is not set in the updated code. Do you set it somewhere else? If it's set, are you sure its value is either Murat_Identity or Murat_Office_Location?

Set last intent to array 1 credit to -(https://stackoverflow.com/users/6196568/shingo) comment
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $intents = [];
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $intents[] = $row['last_intent'];
        }


        $currentIntent = $intents[0];
        $lastIntent=$intents[1];
        
    } 
        
}

